# How to install python module to specific python version on Linux with sudo apt-get

Tags: python, linux

I have python 3.5 packed with Linux and python 3.6 installed by me. I'm trying to install pyaudio module but whatever module that i tried to install via `sudo apt-get install` is available only on python 3.5. I've already set my default python version, if i type python in the terminal it runs the right version, 3.6, but when i install modules goes to 3.5. How can i change this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pip` to install the module ?

assuming you want the module to be installed at python3.6

```
python3.6 -m pip install pandas
```

Comment: Yes but didnt work...returns a lot of errors.